# Basic Assumption in the Time Dilation Equation Derivation

Tags: special-relativity

I am familiar with the way the time dilation equation is derived since I was introduced to it in my sophomore college physics class. It's the standard derivation of a stationary observer watching a man passing in a moving train car and emitting a photon upwards, perpendicular to the horizontal motion. The Pythagorean theorem is then easily applied by assuming that both the traveler and the observer measure the same vertical distance. That assumption is the key to deriving the time dilation equation.

My question is:

How can we logically assume that the vertical distance is equal for both parties? How do we know before we do the calculations that length is NOT contracted vertically? I've tried deriving the equation by not making that assumption and I have failed every time.

Comment: Thats due to symmetry.

Comment: @Paul - I'll need quite a bit more than that. I'm not a physicist. The textbook derivation I speak of offered nothing in the way of logical proof and I have never seen a logical proof of that basic assumption anywhere. I can see why some say it hasn't been rigorously proven.

Comment: I know thats not an satisfactory derivation.
Read special relativity part in the Griffiths book.He explained why lenght contractions are not in the direction perpendicular to motion with the help of very simple thought experiment.

Comment: You can download the book easily.or read Wheeler

Comment: Thanks Paul. I've been confused by the derivation I saw for a very long time to a point of not believing it at all. I'm hoping your source solves that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine a train moving down a set of tracks next to a wall.  Mark on the wall the top of the train (while the train is stationary).  Now, while the train is moving, extend a paintbrush out parallel to the top of the train so it paints a second line on the wall.

If there was any vertical length contraction, then the wall would be smaller when measured by the train, and so they would see the second line painted above the first.  However, the train would be smaller when measured by a stationary observer, who would then see the second line painted below the first.

Since both can not occur, the amount of length contraction perpendicular to the motion must be 0, so both lines are painted at the same height from the point of view of both observers.

Comment: Yep. That does it for me. Thanks to you and Paul above. This is the only logical explanation I've ever seen. I took a look at Paul's source as well...Griffiths. If that had been presented in my college text, confusion would have been abated. My college text wasn't that good on multiple topics.

Comment: i have a question. why is not it possible that something really unintuitive happens(which is logically self consistent) for example :- consider an observer sitting on rooftop of train just at the end of the paint brush. could not it be possible that for him, walls actually have a variable height?? for example, say walls ahead of brush have more height and behind of brush have less height but that just close to brush have same same height. similarly, for an observer sitting on the wall at the end of paint brush, some parts of the train have more height and other parts of the train have less?

Comment: you can see that this unintuitive possibility is still symmetrical